# Django forms: A dynamic integer model choice field always fails form.has_changed()

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So I have a list of items, with an integer associated with each values:
e.g.

```
CAKE = 1
CHOC = 2
CHIPS = 3
```

A model with a field `foo` uses these values as its field, so the model's field is an integer field. This choice selection is not fixed, its dynamic at the point of render.

e.g. foo_choice could be:

```
( (1, "Eat Cake"), (2, "Fancy a choc?) )
```

or say:

```
( (2, "Fancy a choc?"), (9001, "Surprise!") )
```

In order to create a dynamic choice field for an integer field, after much persistance, reading docs, SO, and luck, I eventually got the following solution:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, foo_choices, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foo'].choices = foo_choices

    def clean_foo(self):
        foo = int(self.cleaned_data['foo'])
        return foo

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        field_classes = {
            'foo': forms.ChoiceField,
        }
        widgets = {
            'property_id': forms.Select(),
        }
```

All is good, except when i call `form.has_changed`, the only field which incorrectly reports whether it has changed is 'foo'. The default `to_python` for a choice field is:

```
    def to_python(self, value):
        """Return a string."""
        if value in self.empty_values:
            return ''
        return str(value)
```

As you can see the value is always a string. This is fine, because my clean then changes it to an int. However the problem with the `has_changed` method, is that it checks whether it has changed as follows:

```
if field.has_changed(initial_value, data_value):
```

Where data_value is:

```
data_value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, prefixed_name)
```

The value from the widget will always be a string. The `initial` is created from the `instance` passed in to create the form, so that is the correct data type, i.e. an `int`. So `form.has_changed()` will always compare an `int` to a `str` and report `True` (e.g. comparing 1 to '1').

Is it just me or is this some broken machinery design of Django?  How is one supposed to achieve this?

Comment: Can you use `form.cleaned_data['foo']` to get the value as an integer?

Comment: Hi @justin, yes I can after my own custom clean has run as seen in `def clean_foo(self):` above. In `def clean_foo` the value in cleaned data is a string.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem - form.has_changed()
is always True for IntegerChoices enum fields.

Previously I've filed this [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/34711)  report on the official
Django bug tracker which was followed by a short discussion.

Summary:

- The current behaviour - IntegerChoice always triggers `form.has_changed()` - is not an official bug.
- The canonical way to handle IntegerChoice is to use `form.TypeChoiceField()` with `coerce` defined to the type of value used in the enum.

Taken the example from the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/)

```
class Answer(models.IntegerChoices):
    NO = 0, _("No")
    YES = 1, _("Yes")

    __empty__ = _("(Unknown)")
```

this means that you have to use

```
answerField=forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=sampleModel.Answers.choices, coerce=int)
```

Though not mentioned in the docs, this seems to be
the official way to use an enum form field and avoid
falsely triggering `form.has_changed()`.

This is the current state of discussion for Django 4.2
which - of course - can change in future.